# Visual Studio 2010 Installation Project with Autostart

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autostart

I have .NET4 project with setup wizard from Visual studio 2010.
In shortcut I want do installer project who automatically add my application to autostart and start her after successfull installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Intaller from Visual Studio 2010 don't have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Make your installer add shortcut to startup folder, or add registry key to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. Name of reg key is anything, name of your app in example, and value is path to executable.

Comment: I'm searching some way to do it via MSI installer. I know can do that.

Comment: And what about run executable after success-full install?

Comment: I am sure installer can add registry keys and place shortcuts.